# Promise issue: using Q.nfcall() to call mongoose.findOne()

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, q

I have the following code, where `mongoose`'s `findOne` method is wrapped using `Q.promise`:

```
// _getById should be returning a Promise
var _getById = function(id) {
  return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    ApplicationModel.findOne({
      _id: id,
      'metadata.isDisabled': false
    },
    '-metadata',
    function(err, application) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      if (!application) {
        return reject(new CustomError('Not found', 404));
      }

      resolve(application);
    });

  });
}
```

I am trying to refactor that code using `Q.nfcall` method, and this is what I have so far:

```
var _getById = function(id) {
  var searchOptions = {
    _id: id,
    'metadata.isDisabled': false
  };

  return Q.nfcall(ApplicationModel.findOne, searchOptions, '-metadata')
    .then(function(application) {
      if (!application) {
        throw new CustomError('Not found', 404);
      }
      return application;
    });
}
```

But it is **not working**, and I'm getting the following **error** on screen:

> info:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'discriminatorMapping' of
>   undefined
>       at findOne [...]

It seems that the `findOne` method is not being called properly using `Q.nfcall`, I'm following [Q's API Reference for nfcall function](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnfcallfunc-args) but I can not get to see why.

Comment: Do you know `mongoose` is already promisified? `return ApplicationModel.findOne(ApplicationModel.findOne, searchOptions, '-metadata').then( ... );`

Comment: @ShanShan is it? First notice I have! (I wouldn't be Promisifying if I did ^^)

Comment: Yes, try the code I wrote, it should work. You have an excuse though, mongoose docs are not the easiest to read :p

Comment: @ShanShan hahaha I agree, they aren't the easiest!! Thank you!! :-) I'm gonna try it now. You can post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @ShanShan it perfectly works! go on, answer the question! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose is already promisified. So, your code can simply be:

```
var _getById = function(id) {
  var searchOptions = {
    _id: id,
    'metadata.isDisabled': false
  };

  return ApplicationModel.findOne(searchOptions, '-metadata')
    .then(function(application) {
      if (!application) {
        throw new CustomError('Not found', 404);
      }
      return application;
    });
}
```

Comment: That was very useful!!